# Bootstrap carousel has some aesthetic errors

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have RoR project (rails 4.2.1) and I'm trying to implement a carousel. It mostly works: All images appear in the right order and in the set time interval, but there is no sliding and the `glyphicon-chevron-right` arrow that transitions to the next image is considerably smaller than the left one for the previous image.

I'm using the minified 3.3.7 bootstrap file from MaxCDN and JQuery is being loaded beforehand. For the `glyphicon-chevron-right` issue, I tried increasing the font size via CSS but that didn't work. I also tried using other glyphicons but they were positioned strangely in the carousel and I couldn't position them correctly.

Here's the code for the carousel I have right now (adapted from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)):

```
<%if @firstimg.present?%>
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" style="height:200px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <%if @slideshow.size > 0%>
    <% for i in 1..@slideshow.size%>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to=<%=i%>></li>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src=<%=@firstimg%> alt=<%=@modulo.nome%>>
    </div>

    <%if @slideshow.size > 0%>
        <%@slideshow.each do |s|%>
        <div class="item">
          <img src=<%=s.photo.url%> alt=<%=@modulo.nome%>>
        </div>
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<%end%>
```

And the the relevant CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel {
  width:100%;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  height:200px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

EDIT: The controller:

```
def saiba_mais
    @preco           = preco_modulo(@modulo.id)
    @firstimg        = @modulo.images.first.photo.url
    @slideshow       = @modulo.images.drop(1)
end
```

Comment: can you post your controller code and can i get the project for testing with git?

Comment: I added the controller, but I can't share the full project, I'm sorry...